# List Row Count C#

Tags: c#, arrays

```
public class FlatFileLookUp
{

    public string standard;

    public string newField;
}
```

I want something like this

```
public static string matchHEADER(string filename, List<FlatFileLookUp> myitem)
{
myitem[1].newField.Rows.Count; //not working
}
```

How can i count the rows of list?

Comment: `newField` is a `string`. It does not have Rows. Try `myitem.Count`

Comment: `var counts=myitem.Count;` should return the counts.

Comment: If you are really looking for the `List.Count` property you should have found something with google (or simply use visual studio's intellisense). Otherwise your question isn't clear.

Comment: your question is not sounds clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can i count the rows of list?

You could simple use the `Count` property of a list:

```
myitem.Count
```

Comment: as per coding convention, myItem should be myItems

Comment: @A.T. Correct ! I have used OP namings.

Answer (score -1):

To get the number of records use the following code:

```
int counts = myitem.Count();
```